# Can't decrease Chrome size further

Tags: web-development

Currently doing web dev and I need to see the decrease in window size further than elementary allows horizontally.

Answer (score 1):

Right mouse click into the web page and choose "Inspect element" - it should open the web dev browser inspector with a lot of options for screen sizes including larger than your monitor (with some zoom applied). All browsers should have this option.